# 06 G35 Coupe Engine Compatibility

Tags: engine, infiniti, g35, swap

Following this adventure:

[2006 Infiniti G35 - Blown engine following Kwik Kar engine flush](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/18052/2006-infiniti-g35-blown-engine-following-kwik-kar-engine-flush)

I'm getting ready to put a new engine in my 06 G35 coupe, 6-speed manual (also with RAS, etc. but that shouldn't matter.)

I'm seeing different versions of the VQ35 engine available, called a VQ35**DE**, VQ35 **Rev-Up**, and a VQ35**HR**

Every forum I look at has different thoughts about what the differences are, which one I have, and compatibility (really, swapability) between them.

I *think* I have the "Rev Up" version, but am not entirely sure, and don't really know to tell.

So, the questions:

1. Any idea how I can tell which motor I have?
2. Assuming it's the "Rev Up," will the HR work in its place? (With existing ECU / Harness, transmission, etc.)?

Trying to do this as inexpensively as possible. Thinking of pulling the heads from the current (really, really blown) motor and seeing if they're salvageable. If so, I can get a short block for a sane amount.

I'm open to suggestions. As always, thanks for the help.

**So Sad**

[image: waiting]

[image: engine]

**Update, two years later...**
I wound up replacing the rev-up engine from my car with a non-rev from a JDM 350Z. It took quite a bit of work - these things are not as similar as one would like to think - but it runs just fine.

Comment: Stupid question, but what's the redline show on your tachometer?

Comment: Nothing authoritative here, but what I'm reading shows the 06 G35 with MT to have the Rev-Up motor, while the AT version has the non Rev-Up motor in it. So I'm thinking yours does have the Rev-Up motor. And I really do think it matters which motor you get, as I'm reading about differences in the block height, the engine sitting lower in the engine bay, and a bunch of other physical stuff which would preclude swapping.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 7000

Comment: I'm thinking you have the Rev-Up motor then as well. The redline and your car being a M6 leads me to believe this. I would not trust any other motor but this one to work in your car correctly. Even a short block as stated above.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 sounds great. Thanks. Want to convert this to an answer?

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to tell the difference when browsing Ebay.

Comment: Do a search on ebay for "VQ35DE Rev-Up" and ensure the engine is from an 04-06 G35/Z350 with a manual transmission. Then only pull the trigger when you can verify in the image it has the four sensors.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 awesome - thanks! I just checked my car and verified that it has two harness connectors on each of the heads where I'd expect the sensors to be. Thanks for your help. I really owe you a lot of :beer: at this point.

Comment: No worries ... that's what I'm here for :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you have is the "Rev-Up" motor as you suggested. This stems from the year ('06) and it being a manual transmission. This information was derived several G35 forums as well as what's available as parts through my favorite online parts retailer.

One of the major things which is different about the "Rev-Up" motor is it has variable valve timing on both the intake and exhaust cams, where the regular VQ35DE motor only has a phaser on the intake side. You can readily see where the cam sensors for the engines are at here in this image:

[image]

This is the back side of the engine, with the regular VQ35DE on the left and the "Rev-Up" on the right. The outside holes on the Rev-Up engine are for the sensors on the exhaust cams. The standard VQ35DE doesn't need them. I'm sure there are other tell tale signs as well, but this is something which sticks out to me.

I cannot confirm, but according to "forum" sources, there seems to be slight differences in the blocks as far as how tall the block heights are, as well as engine mount placement. I'm not sure if this is accurate, though. You definitely do not want to use the VQ35HR motor, as this engine is said to be about 80% new compared to the either of these. They all share the same bore and stroke, but the comparison kinda ends there.

Comment: I wish I could invite this twice. Helpful diagrams make (almost) everything better.

Comment: One more thing : where'd you find that image?

Comment: I looked it up on rockauto.com ... they usually have great images. They didn't specify the right one as a "Rev-Up" motor, but did state it was for "Manual Transmission Only". I made screen caps of both engines, trimmed them down, added annotations, and the rest is history.

Answer (score -2):

So I watched a video and the rev up engine only comes in the 2005 to 2006 nissan 350 z just because the infiniti g35 added the extra valve timing to the exhaust side did not make it the rev up version the newer intake and ECU with the addition of the vvt on exhaust side made it a rev up version but if I was ever going to do an engine swap on my g35 sedan it would have to be with the HR version but that would again also require the ECU, engine, and wire harness, and more than likely the transmission also nissan is notoriously known for same engine up front but changing the rear casting to mount different transmissions as I found out while doing my first g35 engine swap there is a video you can watch on dustrunnersauto.com that explains more https://dustrunnersauto.com/vq35de/

Comment: Is this to be an answer to the question?  Please reformat it - the run-on sentence is impossible to read.

Comment: That's incorrect. The '05 350Z did not have the rev-up. The G35 got it first. The replacement engine I got, from an '06 JDM 350Z, is not also not a rev-up. The original motor in my '06 G35 coupe IS a rev-up. The castings on the block, etc. are identical, and the Z motor happily plugged up to my G35 6-speed transmission. The differences are in the wiring harness, heads (obviously) and software.